# Firestore data fetching in wrong order

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I am fetching data from firestore using angular 6. 
I have a collection named users, each document of this collection contains user info and each users can have one of three user roles "Admin", "ASM" or "Salesmen". I use company_code as filter.
Now when I fetch data, only admins of all company_code are fetched, and then after sometime all other users are fetched.
Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here

```
getAllUsers(companycode){
    this.afs.collection('users',ref=>ref
    .where("company_code","==",companycode))
    .snapshotChanges().pipe()
    .map(res=>res.map(res=> res.payload.doc.data()))
    .subscribe(res=>{
         console.log(res)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a `timestamp` field or `precedence` to reference your order.

Step 2. Add `orderBy` in your query

```
getAllUsers(companycode) {
    this.afs.collection('users', ref =>
      ref.where("company_code", "==", companycode).orderBy('timestamp')
    )
      .snapshotChanges().pipe()
      .map(res => res.map(res => res.payload.doc.data()))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
      });
}
```

Assume you are using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md)

Answer (score 0):

To get all company user, Remove this line 
 .where(“company_code”, “==“, companycode)

To get all company salesmen, use
 .where(“comoany_code”, “==“, “salesmen”